# Set Inside Horizontal cell borders

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit of VBA code that attempts to set the LEFT and TOP border on a bunch of non-contiguous cells - previously appended to a Range object based on some criteria. For context, the 'rng' argument is a collection of cells that have values satisfying a certain criterion.
The code that almost totally works is:

```
Private Sub set_cell_borders(rng As Range, change_cat As Long)
    Dim border_colour As Long, the_borders As Variant, i As Long
    the_borders = Array(xlEdgeLeft, xlEdgeTop, xlInsideHorizontal, xlInsideVertical)
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Select Case change_cat
    Case 1: border_colour = RGB(160, 160, 160)  ' Trivial change (grey)
    Case 2: border_colour = RGB(255, 192, 0)    ' Minor change (orange)
    Case 3: border_colour = RGB(255, 0, 0)      ' Major change (red)
    Case 4: border_colour = RGB(102, 0, 204)    ' String change (purple)
    End Select
    
    For i = LBound(the_borders) To UBound(the_borders)
        With rng.Borders(the_borders(i))
            .Color = border_colour
            .Weight = xlThick
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    Next i
Exit Sub
    
errHandler:
    ' Assume we got here if rng is format-protected, so simply exit
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

The cells all format as expected, except the xlInsideVertical and xlInsideHorizontal borders only seem to acknowledge the .LineStyle = xlContinuous line, not the .Width or .Color attributes i.e. I end up with all the TOP and LEFT borders of each contiguous block of cells formatted as expected, but any adjacent cells that should be marked have simply a thin black line between them. For clarity, all cells start from a wiped-format condition (no borders at all), so I know the .LineStyle attribute *is* being applied by my code, not simply exists already in those cells, if that makes sense?

I thought I had this working previously, so I suppose it could be an Excel bug in Excel 365 Version 2202, but wanted to check on here whether I am missing something more fundamental.

Update: added images to clarify the intended (top image) and actual (bottom image) behaviour.

[image: Desired Behaviour]

[image: Actual Behaviour]

Comment: P.S. I suspect that the issue might be to do with the fact 'rng' is non-contiguous, and may therefore contain some cells that have no neighbours (thus Inside borders has no meaning for those cells)

Comment: I can't replicate that. Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this behavior. For me, this happens only for the `xlInsideVertical`-borders (it works for the `xlInsideHorizontal`), and it happens only when you have a non-contiguous range. Checking with the debugger shows that the properties for Weight and Color are not stored. I cannot say if this is a bug or on purpose.

However, there is an easy workaround: Simply loop over all areas within your range. Every Range has a collection of areas (ranges) which represent the (contiguous) range-pieces of that range. Using areas will work also for contiguous ranges: They have a collection with one member, so your code will work in any case.

```
Dim area As Range
For Each area In rng.Areas
    For i = LBound(the_borders) To UBound(the_borders)
        With area.Borders(the_borders(i))
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThick
            .Color = border_colour
        End With
    Next i
Next area
```

**Update**: I did some experiments: The problem does not occur if you have a (non-contiguous) range selected and use `Selection` (or `Set rng = Selection`). However, as soon as you use `Union`, the problem occurs. Anyhow, looping over areas did the job in all cases. And in the meantime, I had also cases where `xlInsideHorizontal` didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas, I am very reluctant to loop as that was almost how my code was a few weeks ago - except I was looping each cell in the Range, and I suspect looping on areas will be a little faster. The problem was it was glacial because of the size of the collection - varies between hundreds and thousands of items, depending on the specific workbook that is running this formatting.

I will try using Selection and see if that allows a single range operation without the issue manifesting.

Comment: To comment further, using rng.Select and then acting on Selection does not work *if the first member of the selection is a cell by itself* i.e. if the ActiveCell is a lone cell, it doesn't work. I will therefore try looping on areas and see what the speed penalty is...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @FunThomas for doing some experimenting - it seems the root cause is if the *first* cell in the 'rng' Range is a lone cell. If the first few cells are contiguous, Excel does not seem bothered by lone cells being part of the collection, it will still apply internal borders for the blocks of contiguous cells as expected.

Therefore, the proper (but slow on large ranges) solution is as @FunThomas suggests - loop through Areas.

In my case, I will think about whether to artificially ensure the first included cell is not isolated from the rest, perhaps by duplicating it in the row below, and then tidying up at the end. This is only worth the effort because my Range is thousands of cells long and the speed difference is noticeable for users, for whom this exercise must be imperceptibly fast.

Comment: Have you set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` during execution?

Comment: Of course :) Not my first rodeo. It is just a huge collection of cells, in many little chunks (i.e. so the number of areas is not much smaller than the number of cells - maybe 20% or so, typically). So it's still many hundreds of format operations vs one...

Comment: If I do the math correct, that means that at least 80% are single cells (which don't have inside borders). You could speed up the process by setting the outside borders for the whole range and then loop over the areas and set the inside borders only if the area contains at least 2 columns (for vertical) resp. 2 rows (for horizontal).

Comment: I think it might be simpler (and quicker) to loop until I find the first cells that *are* contiguous, and then set one of those as the ActiveCell (if this is possible on a cell that isn't the top-left of the whole Range object), and then it seems to work as a single operation... But your partial looping is a good fallback position.